VBA run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)' automation error
I need a code that will merge 200 Excel files into one single document.
The headers and information in the files are the same and are located on pages named "ms". There is a blank "mb" page in the main workbook to which I want to copy data from the workbooks in the "All" folder. An error occurs at the:
`ws.Cells.Copy line`

My code:
`Sub CombineData()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String


myPath = "C:\Users\d.pavlov\Documents\All"

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ms")

e data
Set wsMaster = Workbooks("Master Workbook.xlsx").Sheets("mb")

lastRow = wsMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

myFile = Dir(myPath & "\*.xlsx")

Do While myFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & "\" & myFile)
    ws.Cells.Copy
    wsMaster.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wb.Close False
    lastRow = wsMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    myFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub`

I found an interesting solution, the code works and helped me:
'Option Explicit
 
Sub Consolidated_Range_of_Books_and_Sheets()
    Dim iBeginRange As Range, rCopy As Range, lCalc As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim oAwb As String, sCopyAddress As String, sSheetName As String
    Dim lLastrow As Long, lLastRowMyBook As Long, li As Long, iLastColumn As Integer
    Dim wsSh As Worksheet, wsDataSheet As Worksheet, bPolyBooks As Boolean, avFiles
    Dim wbAct As Workbook
    Dim bPasteValues As Boolean, IsPasteSheetName As Boolean
 
    On Error Resume Next
    'Select a range of samples from books
    Set iBeginRange = Application.InputBox("Select the data collection range." & vbCrLf & _
"1. If you select only one cell, data will be collected from all sheets starting with that cell." & _
vbCrLf & "2. If you select multiple cells, data will be collected only from the specified range of all sheets.",Type:=8)
'to specify a range without a dialog box:
'Set iBeginRange = Range("A1:A10") 'the range is specified as desired
'If the range is not selected, we complete the procedure    
If iBeginRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Specify the sheet name
'It is permissible to specify the ? and * symbols in the sheet name.
'If you specify only *, the data will be collected from all sheets
    sSheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet from which to collect data (if not specified, then data is collected from all sheets)", "Parameter")
    'If the sheet name is not specified, data will be collected from all sheets
    If sSheetName = "" Then
        sSheetName = "*"
    End If
'whether to add sheet name to beginning of table
    IsPasteSheetName = (MsgBox("Insert sheet name as first column?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes)
    On Error GoTo 0
'Query - insert all data into the resulting sheet
'or just cell values (without formulas and formats)
    bPasteValues = (MsgBox("Insert values only?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo= vbYes)
    'Request to collect data from books (if No, then collection is from the active book)
    If MsgBox("Collect data from multiple books?", vbInformation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        avFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files(*.xls*),*.xls*", , "Select files", , True)
        If VarType(avFiles) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub
        bPolyBooks = True
        lCol = 1
    Else
        avFiles = Array(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    End If
    If IsPasteSheetName Then
        lCol = lCol + 1
    End If
    'disable screen refresh, automatic formula recalculation and event tracking
'for code execution speed and to avoid errors if there are other codes in the books    With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlManual
    End With
    'create a new sheet in the book for collection
    Set wsDataSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    'if you need to collect data on a new workbook sheet with the code
'Set wsDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
'loop through books
    For li = LBound(avFiles) To UBound(avFiles)
        If bPolyBooks Then
            Set wbAct = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=avFiles(li))
        Else
            Set wbAct = ThisWorkbook
        End If
        oAwb = wbAct.Name
'cycle by sheets
        For Each wsSh In wbAct.Sheets
            If wsSh.Name Like sSheetName Then
                'If the sheet name matches the name of the sheet in which we are ‘collecting data
'and the collection is only from the active book, then we move on to the next sheet                If wsSh.Name = wsDataSheet.Name And bPolyBooks = False Then GoTo NEXT_
                With wsSh
                    Select Case iBeginRange.Count
                    Case 1 'collect data starting from the specified cell and until the end of the data
                        lLastrow = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
                        iLastColumn = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
                        sCopyAddress = .Range(.Cells(iBeginRange.Row, iBeginRange.Column), .Cells(lLastrow, iLastColumn)).Address
                    Case Else 'collect data from a fixed range
                        sCopyAddress = iBeginRange.Address
                    End Select
                    lLastRowMyBook = wsDataSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1
                    'we define for copying a range of only filled data on the sheet
                    Set rCopy = Intersect(.Range(sCopyAddress).Parent.UsedRange, .Range(sCopyAddress))
                    'insert the name of the book from which the data was collected
                    If lCol > 0 Then
                        If bPolyBooks Then
                            wsDataSheet.Cells(lLastRowMyBook, 1).Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count).Value = oAwb
                        End If
                        If IsPasteSheetName Then
                            wsDataSheet.Cells(lLastRowMyBook, lCol).Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count).Value = .Name
                        End If
                    End If
                   'if we insert only values
                    If bPasteValues Then
                        rCopy.Copy
                        wsDataSheet.Cells(lLastRowMyBook, 1).Offset(, lCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        wsDataSheet.Cells(lLastRowMyBook, 1).Offset(, lCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Else 'if we insert all the cell data (formulas, formats, etc.)                        rCopy.Copy wsDataSheet.Cells(lLastRowMyBook, 1).Offset(, lCol)
                    End If
                End With
            End If
NEXT_:
        Next wsSh
        If bPolyBooks Then
            wbAct.Close False
        End If
    Next li
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = lCalc
    End With
End Sub'


change ws.Cells.Copy to wb.Sheets("ms").UsedRange.Copy. Do you want the header copied for all files or just the first ?

just the first. thx :)

Option Explicit

Sub CombineData()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\d.pavlov\Documents\All"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsMaster As Worksheet, rngTo As Range
    Dim myFile As String, r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set wsMaster = Workbooks("Master Workbook.xlsx").Sheets("mb")
    With wsMaster
        Set rngTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    myFile = Dir(FOLDER & "\*.xlsx")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FOLDER & "\" & myFile)
        With wb.Sheets("ms")
            r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            rngTo.Resize(r, c).Value = .Range("A1").Resize(r, c).Value
            Set rngTo = rngTo.Offset(r)
            n = n + 1
        End With
        wb.Close False
        
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox n & " files imported from " & FOLDER, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub

